# What happens if you fly a drone inside moving passenger airplane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, relative-motion

I have a little question. If I mark an X in the center of a passenger airplane, and try to fly a drone from the X mark in the moving passenger airplane (800-900 km/h), what will happen to the drone? 
Is it going to fly up and standstill above the X mark? Or will it fly up above the X mark then gradually heading to the end of the plane? Put aside the FAA rules and something like that.

Comment: Drone and airplane are fixed with respect to each other before you try to fly the drone. (Initial speed of drone is $800-900\mathrm{kph}$)

Comment: Do NOT try this in the real world, unless you are willing to either pay a large fine or spend a few years in prison!

Comment: @DavidWhite Will do, i'm just curious not gonna try it in real world.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20333/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drone flies by its propellers exercising force against the air inside the airplane. It flies with respect to the air inside the airplane. Since the air is being carried by the airplane, the drone will fly with respect to the airplane. It'll fly forward or in whichever direction you point it, with respect to the X. Assuming the airplane is airtight.

Comment: Minor detail. Everithing assumes the airplane is at constant velocity. If the airplane were accelerating then the drone would drift a wrt the X

Comment: @Joafigue Finer minor detail. Everithing above assumes the airplane accelerating on plane perpendicular to gravitational force. If the airplane were accelerating in the direction of gravitational force then the drone will not drift.

Comment: @alvinwijaya. Glad to be of help. In physics some intuition (in this case the air moves with the airplane, more or less) is often not stated and you have to figure out what they don't tell you.